# gRPC Not being generated

Tags: c#, grpc

I am currently trying to implement a gRPC server in an existing C# ASP .NET Core application. But the C# bindings aren't being generated to use within the application. I have installed the following dependencies:

- Grpc
- Google.Protobuf
- Grpc.Core
- Grpc.Tools

I have added the `.proto` file to the `Protos` folder in my project. I have the following `.proto` configuration:

```
syntax = "proto3";

//Request that comes through from the microservice endpoint
message RegistrationRequest {
    string type = 1;
    string ipAddress = 2;
}

//Response on the service register endpoint
message RegistrationResponse {
    bool accepted = 1;
}

//Request to get API endpoint to use based on type
message HostRequest {
    string type = 1;
}

//Response of the host request
message HostResponse {
    string ipAddress = 1;
}

//Service for the repository
service ServiceRepoServer {
    //Method that will register the endpoint on the repo
    rpc RegisterEndpoint (RegistrationRequest) returns (RegistrationResponse) {}
    //Method that will return an endpoint based on type
    rpc RequestEndpoint (HostRequest) returns (HostResponse) {}
}
```

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding to no avail. It is probably somethind small I am missing somewhere but I am not sure what it is. Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Did you edit csproj file?

Comment: Also, are you using .Net Core 3.0?

Comment: @LeisenChang - Using .NET Core 3.0 and no I didn't edit the csproj file. Is there something that needs to be added there?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to edit csproj, for example the default greet.proto does this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Protobuf Include="Protos\greet.proto" GrpcServices="Server" />
</ItemGroup>
```

`GrpcServices` parameter can also be `Client` or `Both` depends on what you need.

If you're using Visual Studio 2019, you can also use build action to do this. Right click on your proto file and select properties. Choose `Protobuf compiler` in `Build Action`

[image]

Comment: The Grpc project also ships a .NET global tool, [dotnet-grpc](https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/grpc/dotnet-grpc) that allows you to manage your protobuf references.

See the documentation at https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/grpc/dotnet-grpc

Comment: So what if we've added the path(s) to our proto files but still we are not getting service classes generated? :)